# Receiving AttributeError from os.path.isfile() function

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyscripter

Receiving the below error when running my script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HC_Main.py", line 54, in <module>
    setup_exists = os.path.isfile(config_file)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'isfile'
```

Sample code is:

```
import os
setup_exists = os.path.isfile(setup_exists)
if setup_exists is False:
    print "Setup file exists"
```

When I checked the IDLE console with `dir(os.path)`, `isfile` is listed. Additionaly, I can use the function without issues in IDLE as well.

Could it be my IDE causing issues here? I've also tried running the script apart from the IDE, but it still receives the error.

Answer (score 3):

Somehow, `os.path` is no longer the builtin module, but it has been replaced with a function.  Check your code to make sure you didn't accidentally monkey-patch it somewhere.

For clues, you could start by putting:

```
print os.path
```

right before the line where you actually use `os.path.isfile`.  This should give you the function's name which will hopefully give you a good place to start looking.

Comment: `print os.path` gives me `<module 'ntpath' from 'C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.pyc'>`. Not sure what that is.

Comment: @user3492006 -- that makes no sense with the AttributeError you posted.  The attributeError says that a __'function'__ has no attribute `'isfile'`, but you're saying that printing `os.path` does in fact return a `module` (which should have `isfile` defined within).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
import os.path
```

instead

see this thread for more info:   [How do I check whether a file exists using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-using-python?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I had an if/else statement earlier in the code, which was being used to gather the OS version the script was running on. Turns out I used OS (caps) for the variable name, which I think caused this. I changed it around, and it's fixed.